# Linux : how to set default route from C?

Tags: linux, networking, routes, posix

How can I set (and replace the existing) default network route from a C program?  I'd like to do it without shell commands if possible (this is a low memory embedded system).  Also can you set the default route without specifying the gateway IP address?  In my application I want to make either ppp0 or eth0 the default route, depending on whether the cable is plugged into eth0 or not.

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: Why do you want to avoid shell commands?

Comment: Too indirect and can use a lot of RAM.  This is on a small embedded system.  I programmed a system a while back that would actually crash because it used too much ram shelling out to a busybox command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `strace` the `route`  command you are wanting to mimic. This gives you the relevant syscalls useful to change routing.

You may be interested by the [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) interface, e.g. its `/proc/net/route` pseudo-file.

See also [ip(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html).

Answer (score 13):

You can make IOCTL calls to set the default route from a C program.

```
void main()
{
   int sockfd;
   struct rtentry rt;

   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   if (sockfd == -1)
   {
      perror("socket creation failed\n");
      return;
   }

   struct sockaddr_in *sockinfo = (struct sockaddr_in *)&rt.rt_gateway;
   sockinfo->sin_family = AF_INET;
   sockinfo->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("Your Address");

   sockinfo = (struct sockaddr_in *)&rt.rt_dst;
   sockinfo->sin_family = AF_INET;
   sockinfo->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

   sockinfo = (struct sockaddr_in *)&rt.rt_genmask;
   sockinfo->sin_family = AF_INET;
   sockinfo->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

   rt.rt_flags = RTF_UP | RTF_GATEWAY;
   rt.rt_dev = "eth0";

   if(ioctl(sockfd, SIOCADDRT, &rt) < 0 )
       perror("ioctl");

   return;
}
```

Comment: if you make this into a function, don't forget to close the socket