# How to get gateway ip and nameserver ip using ioctl in linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, ioctl

I have got ip, subnet and broadcast address using ioctl call.
but don't know how to get default gateway and nameserver ip.
if I pick nameserver from `/etc/resolv.conf` then is it reliable?

Here is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
char buf[1024];
struct ifconf ifc;
struct ifreq *ifr;
int sck, nInterfaces;
int i;
unsigned char mac[6];

sck = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if(sck < 0)
{
    perror("socket");
    return 1;
}

ifc.ifc_len = sizeof(buf);
ifc.ifc_buf = buf;
if(ioctl(sck, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifc) < 0)
{
    perror("ioctl(SIOCGIFCONF)");
    return 1;
}

ifr = ifc.ifc_req;
nInterfaces = ifc.ifc_len / sizeof(struct ifreq);
for(i = 0; i < nInterfaces; i++)
{
    struct ifreq *item = &ifr[i];
    printf("Interface Name = %s\nIP = %s\n",
           item->ifr_name,
           inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&item->ifr_addr)->sin_addr));

    ioctl(sck, SIOCGIFNETMASK, item);
    printf("SubNet Mask = %s\n", inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&item->ifr_netmask)->sin_addr));

    ioctl(sck, SIOCGIFBRDADDR, item);
    printf("BroadCat Address = %s\n", inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&item->ifr_broadaddr)->sin_addr));

    ioctl(sck, SIOCGIFHWADDR, item);
    memcpy(mac, item->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, 6);
    printf("MAC:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n",mac[0],mac[1],mac[2],mac[3],mac[4],mac[5]); 
}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't get nameserver with ioctl because name resolution is not handled by kernel. It lives in deeps of glibc library.

Comment: @myaut : But what about gateway? then from where do i get nameserver IP?  can you help me??

Comment: check the following code - [link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/howto-find-gateway-address-through-code-397078/#post4913964)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the default gateway you can parse `/proc/net/route`:

```
# cat /proc/net/route
Iface   Destination     Gateway         Flags   RefCnt  Use     Metric  Mask   MTU      Window  IRTT
eth0    00000000        010110AC        0003    0       0       0       000000000       0       0
```

If you need nameserver address, parsing `/etc/resolv.conf` seems like a reliable option to me.

Comment: Please be careful when using `/etc/resolv.conf`, in my case DHCPCD overrides the nameservers (execute `resolvconf -l`) that are listed in `/etc/resolv.conf` without updating that file. Therefore the actual nameservers used are different from what is listed in the configuration.

Comment: @Yeti You probably have set `nohook resolv.conf` in your DHCPCD config. That option prevents DHCPCD from updating the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
struct rtentry route;
(...)
ioctl(sck, SIOCADDRT, &route)
```

More information her:

- [How to change default gateway vie C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733967/linux-how-to-set-default-route-from-c/22751236)
- [Linux how to set default route from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178084/how-to-change-default-gateway-vie-c)