# How to Change default gateway vie C

Tags: c, ip, gateway, ioctl

I am trying to write a program in C that will change the default gateway.

I have run the following code: [Linux : how to set default route from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733967/linux-how-to-set-default-route-from-c) 
The code presented here is not working as i would imagine.
It adds a default gateway with a high metric number next to it.
I read about the metric numbers but this is clearly not my goal.
I would like to swap the current default address with one of my own.

If you add some code, an explanation near it would also be much appreciated since it's the first time working with ioctl. Not that familiar with how it work's or why so many things needed to be added to define it.

P.S. please avoid any responses that require me to open files or string manipulations.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a piece of code to define the default gateway

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <net/route.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main(char** args) {
  int sockfd;
  struct rtentry route;
  struct sockaddr_in *addr;
  int err = 0;

  // create the socket
 if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)))<0){
perror("socket");
exit(1);
}

  memset(&route, 0, sizeof(route));
  addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_gateway;
  addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.2.1");
  addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_dst;
  addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_genmask;
  addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  // You need to add the interface name to the request
  route.rt_flags = RTF_UP | RTF_GATEWAY;
  route.rt_metric = 0;
  if ((err = ioctl(sockfd, SIOCADDRT, &route)) != 0) {
    perror("SIOCADDRT failed");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

It uses only simple IOCTL concepts. If you have problems with these notions I advise you to take a look at the link below :
[IOCTL Man Page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html)

Comment: I appreciate the response and I have read all the man pages.
But if u run this code - even with rt_metric=0 it just adds a default getaway instead of replacing it.

Comment: The `SIOCDELRT` ioctl can be used to remove entries from the routing table, so you could remove the old one and add a new one.