# How to elevate privilege level to root from c++ program on linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, userid

I would like to change my default gateway from C++ code. I am using eclipse as an IDE. Following is my code.

```
//change_gw.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;
//To execute terminal commands
std::string exec(char* cmd) {
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int euid = geteuid();
    int uid = getuid();
    cout<<"euid is "<<euid<<endl;
    cout<<"uid is "<<uid<<endl;
    int result = setreuid(euid,-1); //change the uid to euid (0 - root)
    if(result != 0) {
        cout<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    string result = exec("sudo route del default");
    if (result == "ERROR") {
        cout<<"del route failed"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    result = exec("sudo route add default gw ip dev iface");
    if (result == "ERROR") {
        cout<<"add route failed"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout<<"route changed succefully"<<endl;
    setreuid(uid,-1); //revert the changes to uid
    return 0;
}
```

I have successfully compiled this code and obtained the executable. Compilation is done from the eclipse environment. I did the following changes to executable manually from terminal.

```
chown root:root change_gw //change the owner to root
chmod u+s change_gw //set user id
```

Now when I run the executable from eclipse environment, I get this following output.

```
euid = 0
uid = 1002
route changed successfully
```

Although the code above works fine,I would like to know weather the way I am doing is correct and efficient one. And since compilation is done on eclipse environment the user of the executable changes from root to local user every time and I need to change the setuserid flag every time. How could I avoid doing this change every time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733967/linux-how-to-set-default-route-from-c explains how to modify the route table without going via a command.

Comment: Do you want anyone to be able to add this route?  If not, just leave the user as local user, and then they will have to enter their password to change the routing table.  If you *do* want the program to be setuid, you need to search for the precautions you have to take if you don't want to be a gaping security hole.

Comment: Final comment - exec doesn't take a single string as argument.  You have to prepare an array of (modifiable) strings as argv.

Answer (score 0):

The `setreuid()` call is not needed. The suid bit on your executable is sufficient, and does exactly the same thing. This `setreuid()` call ends up doing nothing here.

You may or may not need to execute `setgid()` or `setuid()` if there is anything else you need to do which requires this.